# How to create "button" tag dynamically using $A.createComponent

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

> I am able to dynamically create "ui:button" using $A.createComponent as shown in:
> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm
>
> However, I am not able to do the same for  "button". Can somebody help me why is this happening and also how to render "button".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `aura:html` to create a html tag dynamically using `$A.createComponent`.

So to create a button tag below is how you do it:

```
$A.createComponent(
    "aura:html",
    {
        "tag":"button",
        "body":"click me",
        "HTMLAttributes":{
            "id":"dynamicbtn",
            "class":"slds-button slds-button--brand"
        }
    },
    function(newBtn){
        if (cmp.isValid()) {
            var body = cmp.get("v.body");
            body.push(newBtn);
            cmp.set("v.body", cmp);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, it did render the button the way I wanted!!! One more question here, on click of this  button it is giving me error:   "[TypeError: event.getSource is not a function]". I have used event.getSource() to get ID of  button pressed in controller which it is not accepting I think. Will really appreciate if you would guide on this as well!!

Comment: `event.getSource()` works only for ui namespaced component(i.e aura component).you can get the id of the button using `event.getAttribute('id')`.

Comment: Ah my bad it's *event.target.getAttribute('id')*

Comment: Its not getting 'event' itself in the controller on click, I tried seeing event using alert(event) but it is showing error: 'Something has gone wrong. $A.getDefinition. Please try again.'    Sorry for bad editing

Comment: Ok I'll update the answer which contains click event attached to the button

Comment: It worked!! I think I did some single quote/double quote mistake...but anyways thanks a lot again!!!